# Uploadify for IIS 7, saving to a subfolder

Tags: configuration, iis-7, forms-authentication, uploadify

Uploadify works for Visual Studio but not for IIS 7 (same machines), using Forms authentication.  Does anyone have a working uploadify configuration for IIS 7 where they save to a subfolder?

I'm using the Uploadify jQuery control for client-side uploads.

I think my IIS 7 configuration has issues with it. The uploadify POST immediately returns a HTTP 1.1 302 Found, back to my login page.

I've tried to allow anonymous access to the uploading section(subfolder) plus the page(script) that processes the image in the web.config, using the location node(configuration ... location). Seems like the Uploadify post is immediately blocked.

Again, this worked fine just using Visual Studio 2008, but when I run the site on the same machine I get the redirect.

Your thoughts/ideas are very welcomed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the many nested master pages included Forms Authentication code to ensure the user was authenticated. This was the source of the redirect ...

Comment: If this was the answer to the question please mark it as so for the benefit of other users. Thanks

Comment: drachenstern: I believe at the time I was unable to mark the answer, but was now able to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you. Check path of your `*.axd` script. When you have path like `uploader.axd` uploader work fine only in root. Try path with slash like this -> `/uploader.axd`.